# netsh.exe error on initializing NDI with custom console

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that works with `NDI`. But when I initialize it, error occurs: window with title `"netsh.exe - Application Error"` and error description - `"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application"`. I skip this error and all the required `NDI` functionality works fine. But this error shouldn't occur anyway. I also found, that this error because of my "custom console" usage - my application is GUI-application and I want to see console window near it in some cases.

Very simplified but problem-contains example of this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "ndi/Processing.NDI.Lib.h"

int main()
{
    FreeConsole();
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL));

    HMODULE m_NDIHandler = LoadLibraryA("Processing.NDI.Lib.x64.dll");

    const NDIlib_v5* (*NDIlib_v5_load)(void) = NULL;
    if (m_NDIHandler)
    {
        *((FARPROC*)&NDIlib_v5_load) = GetProcAddress(m_NDIHandler, "NDIlib_v5_load");
    }

    const NDIlib_v5* m_NDILib = NDIlib_v5_load();

    m_NDILib->initialize();

    return 0;
}
```

(Later I'm using `WriteConsole` for some purposes). Could you please tell me, what is wrong with my code? Error occur on `m_NDILib->initialize();`

Answer (score 0):

I updated my NDI to latest version (5.1.3.0) and problem fixed.